# Google Sheets-Last Populated Cell in Column-Above Current Cell

Tags: google-sheets, cell

In A,5 I have a numeric value, in A,15 I have a numeric value. There are blank gaps in the column. In A,10 I want to find the last populated cell in the A column, above the current cell, A,10. The result should return A,5.

I am completely stumped on how to accomplish this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, you want to get the last value in column A to be stored in A10, but you have values past A15? Can you clarify?

Comment: See Chris Hick's answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want in cell A10:

`=+sort(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1)<>"",,row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1)),)`

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem exactly as I described. :)